# Return multiple values using Python code in Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I am building a Zapier Zap using Custom Code - Python as one of the steps.  I need this code to return 2 values for use in down stream tasks.

I can return 1 value easily - visits_startdatetime.  I added vists_name to the loop and return at the end but I only get one value returned.

```
    # 1. Convert the input data from a string to a array. 
visits_signedin = input['visits_signedin']
visits_signedin = list(visits_signedin.split(","))
visits_startdatetime = input_data['visits_startdatetime']
visits_startdatetime = list(visits_startdatetime.split(","))
visits_name = input['visits_name']
visits_name = list(visits_name.split(","))

#2. Loop through the array to find the first true value and return the startdatetime. If none is found, return nothing
for i in range(0, len(visits_signedin)):
    if visits_signedin[i] == "True":
        return {"visits_startdatetime": visits_startdatetime[i]} 
        return {visits_name": visits_name[i]}

return {"visits_startdatetime", "visits_name"}
```

I expect the output to be "12-1-2019" and "Yoga Class".  The actual output is "12-1-2019"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in every other programming language, `return` terminates the function execution and provides the return value to its caller.

Any code after the `return` statement will not run.

If you need to return multiple values, you can return a dictionary with two entries:

```py
return {
    "visits_startdatetime": visits_startdatetime[i],
    "visits_name": visits_name[i]
}

# if no result
return {
    "visits_startdatetime": None,
    "visits_name": None
}
```

or in your case, a cleaner way to do it would be:

```py
visits_startdatetime = None
visits_name = None
for i in range(0, len(visits_signedin)):
    if visits_signedin[i] == "True":
        visits_startdatetime = visits_startdatetime[i]
        visits_name = visits_name[i]

return {"visits_startdatetime": visits_startdatetime, "visits_name": visits_name}
```

Comment: Hi Pierre.  You solved it!  Thank you so much for the detailed and precise response.  Appreciate the time Pierre.